# Determining bounds for change sum of continuous r.v.'s

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, actuarial-science

I'm trying to understand how to determine the bounds when computing the sum of continuous random variables.

Here is a sample question:

X and Y have the following joint pdf:

$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 4xy, 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1$,

If $Z = X + Y$, calculate $f_z(z)$.

So I know that there should be two components to $f_z(z)$:

$f_z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{x,y}(x,z-x) dx $

i)$\large = \int_{0}^z 4x(z-x)dx = \frac{2z^3}{3}$

ii)$\large = f_z(z) = \int_{z-1}^1 4x(z-x) dx = 4z - \frac{2x^3}{3} - 8/3$

My question is how to is one to go about finding the bounds of the integrals (i.e. $(0,z)$ and $(z-1, 1)$)?

Is there a way to do this without drawing out a plot?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been given that $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases}4xy & : 0 \leq x \leq 1,\; 0 \leq y \leq 1\\ 0 & : \text{ elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

You wish to know where $f_{X,Y}(x, z-x)$ is supported (ie: not zero) with respect to $x$, for values of $z$ where $0\leq z\leq 2$.   (Since $z=x+y$, then $0+0\leq z\leq 1+1$.)

$$f_{X,Y}(x,z-x) = \begin{cases}4x(z-x) & : 0 \leq x \leq 1,\; 0 \leq (z-x) \leq 1,\quad 0\leq z\leq 2\\ 0 &: \text{ elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

So this is where: $0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq z-x\leq 1$

With a little rearranging: $0\leq x\leq 1, z-1\leq x\leq z$

So we integrate with respect to $x$ over the interval $\max(0, z-1)\leq x \leq \min(1,z)$ where $0\leq z\leq 2$$

But functions of $\min$ and $\max$ are messy to deal with, so we partition this depending on $z$ so that:$$\Big[0\leq z\leq 1, 0\leq x\leq z\Big]\cup\Big[1< z\leq 2, z-1\leq x\leq 1\Big]$$

Hence: $$f_{X+Y}(z) = \begin{cases}\int_0^z f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)\operatorname d x & : 0\leq z\leq 1\\[1ex]\int_{z-1}^1 f_{X,Y}(x, z-x)\operatorname d x & : 1< z\leq 2 \\[1ex] 0 & :\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Comment: The most important remark in this context might be that the condition $0<z<2$ need not be imposed from the start, it comes naturally into play. For example $f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)=4x(z-x)$ if $0<x,z-x<1$ and $0$ elsewhere, with no qualification. Later on, the integral with respect to $x$ is over the interval $\max(0,z-1)<x<\min(1,z)$... which is empty unless $0<z<2$. This makes the approach to solving this kind of question, entirely automatized.